# How to put HTML Tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone can help how to put HTML `&nbsp;` tag in Javascript code below?
My plan is to have a space after word "entries".

[image]

Below are the Javascript code.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('.data-table-export').DataTable({
                scrollCollapse: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                responsive: true,
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: "datatable-nosort",
                    orderable: false,
                }],
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "language": {
                    "info": "_START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
                    searchPlaceholder: "Search"
                },
                dom: 'Bfltip',
                buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print'
                ]
            });
});
```

Comment: This may because the outer div (or some element) does not have enough width. Try adding style="width:100%" to outer element

Comment: Ideally you should keep your text string immutated, and apply visual spacing through the use of css.   
The best way to do it would be to add some `margin-left` to the button-group next to your string.    
What's the class of the button-group with "copy, csv, pdf, print"?

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using CSS:

```
.data-table-export select {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This won't achieve exactly what you're after, as I do not know the HTML structure returned by .DataTable, but you could certainly adapt it to your needs!

Since the question has a `js` tag, you could do `$('.data-table-export X').css('marginLeft', '10px')` where X is the selector for the first button.

Comment: I think you might mean `.data-table-export {margin-left:10px}` ... ?

Comment: @gibberish if it were something like `button:first-of-type`, then sure! And yes, first stab was very invalid CSS, oops!

Comment: I agree - spacing should be done with css not with adding non-breaking spaces to the html

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
"info": "_START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_ entries"
```

to

```
"info": "_START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_ entries "
```

Or update info section CSS

```
.dataTables_info{
   padding-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: Just apply and nothing change.

Comment: did you try "info": "_START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_ entries  &nbsp;" ?

Comment: already answered above for your both solutions but nothing changes happen :-)